# payable function

Tags: solidity

```
function chance(string memory str) public view returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory strBytes = bytes(str);
        bytes memory result = new bytes(4);
        for(uint i = 8; i < strBytes.length; i++) {
            result[i-8] = strBytes[i];
        }
        return string(result);
    }
```

why calling of this function reterns me an error
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.

how fix this?

Comment: are u sending ether while calling the function?

Comment: What's the value of `str`? An string longer than 12 bytes will make the function revert.